# Kafka-Setting up eclipse to debug Scala/Java Mixed Projects

Tags: eclipse, debugging, apache-kafka

Does anyone know how to debug kakfa cluster using Eclipse? I tried to add a debug configuration for remote Java Application, and then adding debug port 5005. But couldn't get the debugger started. I also downloaded and added Scala IDE plugin from Eclipse Marketplace, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated.